# Casting errors when attempting to return an IQueryable<MyType>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, casting

I have a query that ought to return an `IQueryable<MyType>`.  The code looks like this:

```
public IQueryable<MyType> GetFooList()
{
    var query = (from x in dbContext.TableX
                 join y in dbContext.TableY on x.our_id equals y.our_id 
                 join z in dbContext.TableZ on y.our_id equals z.our_id 
                 join a in dbContext.TableA on z.other_id equals a.other_id 
                 where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.status)
                 select new
                 {
                   (fields....)
                 })
                 .AsQueryable();
    IQueryable<MyType> result = (IQueryable<MyType>) query;
    return result;
}
```

In the calling controller actions, I want to filter this list for values specified at run time; the parameters to filter for will differ between the various calling actions.  E.g.:

```
List<MyType> FooList = Interface.GetFooList()
    .Where( specific conditions )
    .ToList();
```

On the line setting `result`, an exception gets raised:

**Invalid Cast Exception was unhandled by user code**

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery'1[<>f__AnonymousType9'9[System.String,System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime],System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Int32,System.Nullable'1[System.DateTime],System.Nullable'1[System.DateTime]]]'
>   to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable'1[MyType]'.

So I figured this was a casting problem, and added `.Cast<MyType>()` before the call to `AsQueryable()`.  This generates a different error:

> Unable to cast the type 'Anonymous type' to type 'MyType'. LINQ to
>   Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

And if I don't do any casting, these errors get raised in the calling actions instead of the Entity Frameworks accessor.

I've tried the suggestions in all the linked "Similar Questions", to no avail -- the errors keep going back and forth.  I even tried including `.Select(obj => new MyType() {fields...} )` to get away from the anonymous type.  That didn't work either.

I feel like I'm missing something subtly obvious.

**Edited to add**

I updated the code to select a type: `select new MyType() {fields...}`.  This worked properly.  Then the calling method threw a **NotSupportedException**, on the line where I filter the results and make a list from the query:

> The entity or complex type 'MyType' cannot be constructed in a
>   LINQ to Entities query.

**ETA2**

I copied the EF table properties to a new class, MyTypeDTO.  I replaced all use of MyType with MyTypeDTO.  I got this error:

> The specified type member 'our_id' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

Here's the property in the DTO:

```
public int our_id { get; set; }
```

So I removed the get/set, rebuilt, and reran.  Nope, I got the same error.

Comment: You are creating an anonymous type in your select instead of your intended return type, that part is definitely incorrect.

Comment: use `select new MyType` instead of anonymous.  Then you won't need the cast

Comment: `I even tried including .Select(obj => new MyType() {fields...} ) to get away from the anonymous type. That didn't work either.`  What didn't work about it?  What was the error?

Comment: Let me uncomment that section, rerun it, and post the results.  (Flips hour glass.)

Comment: I think this is working with retrieving the query into an `IQueryable<MyTypeDTO>` variable, then performing the `Where()` query on the local variable.  I'll have to test with some data; afterwards, I'll update this with my results.

Comment: Everything works **except** the `Where()` clause.  I'm still getting issues with the DTO and the our_id parameter, as previously specified in ETA2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was incredibly subtle.  One of the fields in the query's anonymous type did not exist in `MyType`.  I discovered this while I was creating a view model to use in this method.

For what it's worth, the view model works just fine.  Eg:

```
public IQueryable<MyViewModel> GetFooList(int parameter)
{
    var query = (from x in dbContext.TableX
                 join y in dbContext.TableY on x.our_id equals y.our_id
                 join z in dbContext.TableZ on y.our_id equals z.our_id
                 join a in dbContext.TableA on z.other_id  equals a.other_id 
                 where x.their_id == parameter
                 select new MyViewModel()
                 {
                    field1 = x.field1,
                    field2 = y.field2,
                    field3 = z.field3 //<= this field did not exist in MyType
                 }
                 ).AsQueryable();

    return query;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You are correct, the reason why all of your casts have failed is that an anonymous type (i.e. the thing you create with `select new {...}` construct) cannot be cast to a named type.

> I even tried including `.Select(obj => new MyType() {fields...} )` to get away from the anonymous type. That didn't work either.

You were on the right track - this should work, assuming that `MyType` has the appropriate setters:

```
 var query = from x in dbContext.TableX
             join y in dbContext.TableY on x.our_id equals y.our_id 
             join z in dbContext.TableZ on y.our_id equals z.our_id 
             join a in dbContext.TableA on z.other_id equals a.other_id 
             where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.status)
             select new MyType
             {
                MyTypeField1 = a.Column1
             ,  MyTypeField2 = z.Column3
             ,  // ...and so on
             }; // No need to convert to IQueryable - this should produce the right type
return result;
```

> The entity or complex type `'MyType'` cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

This is because `MyType` is a mapped entity. You should not be creating projections that return mapped entities, so EF correctly restricts your ability to do so. You should be able to project into a non-mapped type (to create a so-called DTO - data transfer object).

Define a class `MyTypeDto` which has the properties of `MyClass`, but no methods or mappings. Use `MyClassDto` in the definition of your method. This should fix the problem.

Comment: Nope, same-ish error as my first edit.  The difference is that instead of the error being with the complex type `(namespace).MyType`, now it's with `EFModel.MyType` (where "EFModel" is the Entity Frameworks model).

Comment: your suggestion to use a DTO for a strongly typed IQueryable helped me to the solution.  :beer: