# What does the # sign in AnonymousType0#1`6 mean?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

As you can see in the error line below the two AnonymousType0 texts are almost the same except for the # sign. What does the # sign mean?

*(error reformatted to make it easier to read)*

> Unable to cast object of type
>
> ```
> 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[
>     <>f__AnonymousType0#1`6[System.String,System.String,System.String,
>     System.Int32,System.Decimal,System.Double]]'
> ```
>
> to type
>
> ```
> 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[
>     <>f__AnonymousType0`6[System.String,System.String,System.String,
>     System.Int32,System.Decimal,System.Double]]'
> ```

Comment: Do you have the code which produces this exception?

Comment: I'll simplify the code into test code after I look into @Darth Veyda suggestion and post it afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from these two questions

[Casting errors when attempting to return an IQueryable<MyType>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906520/casting-errors-when-attempting-to-return-an-iqueryablemytype)

and

[Combine two EF Queries, Unable to cast object of type System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20788129/combine-two-ef-queries-unable-to-cast-object-of-type-system-data-entity-infrast)

it's likely you cannot cast because your anonymous types don't quite match each other (so *#1* may be there to indicate that this is not the same type).

Try checking if both types have the exact same set of properties (same types AND same names; no extra properties that are declared in one type but not the other).

Good luck!

Comment: I'll check this out. I'm up voting you. Sorry it won't let me because I have low reputation.

Comment: No worries :) (If my suggestion helps, I think you can still tick the answer as accepted even if you cannot upvote ;))

Comment: I'm accepting this answer. Its led me to post another question.